# connecting Postgres database via doctrine in Heroku

Tags: postgresql, symfony, heroku, web-deployment

I am running a Symfony app on Heroku. It uses a Postgres database. I want to connect to the database by running

`heroku run php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

and it gives me this error message 
`[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                        An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.`

although i can access the database by running

`heroku pg:psql`

Comment: You have created user in your heroku database?

Comment: only the default user they created during setup via GUI @mtaqi

Comment: Try granting permission `GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE dbname TO user_name;` what it says then?

Comment: i tried this command with owner user and with db user and still nothing

Comment: the command prints nothing at all

Comment: oh, then you have to create database first, `doctrine:database:create` works for mysql, but not for PostgreSQL, you need explicit permissions for that, try run `doctrine:database:update --force`.

Comment: Heroku already creates the database for you, and you cant run `doctrine:database:create` or `doctrine:database:drop` because you don't have permissions.
You just need to run the migrations via `doctrine:database:update --force`.

Comment: you are totally right thanks 
just one thing it's `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` 
please make it as answer to accept